# Suppose $p$ is an odd prime, and $5a^2\equiv-1\pmod{p}$, show $p$ is congruent to $1,3,7,9\pmod{20}$

Tags: number-theory

I know that I need to use quadratic reciprocity here. The furthest I got is $\;x^2\equiv(-1)\cdot\text{inverse of }5\pmod{p}$, how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Hint : $-5$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ and $p=5$ is impossible.

Comment: If  $p$ is an odd prime then $-1$ is  a square mod $p$ iff $4|(p-1).$  So if $4|(p-1)$ then  $a$ exists iff $5$ is a non-zero square mod $p$ . Or if $4\not |(p-1)$  then $a$ exists iff $5$ is   a non-square mod $p$. Apply Quadratic Reciprocity separately for these rwo cases.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Fermat little theorem:

$a^2\equiv 1\bmod 3\Rightarrow 5a^2\equiv 5\bmod 3=3k+5$

If k is even then $5a^2\equiv 5 \bmod 6\equiv -1 \bmod 6$

So P can be of the form $6k+5$. or equivalently $6k-1$ For example:

K= 3, 4, 6, 7 and 8 give

$P=23\equiv 3\bmod 20$

$P=29\equiv 9\bmod 20$

$P=41\equiv 1\bmod 20$

$P=47\equiv 7\bmod 20$

And it repeats for higher k.